# Why transliteration not working for dynamically adding input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vue-component

For the first input field present, transliteration is working perfectly. But when I add @addNeWrow, input field appears, but transliteration is working. I need to work transliteration for all the input fields I am adding via @addNewRow

I need to dynamically add input fields. In that case, for the first input field transliteration is working. For the second input field onwards transliteration is not working. Because transliteration id works only for one input field. So, how can I able to change id of input field and transliteration id dynamically? 
So, the code for dynamically adding input fields is

```
   <div class="row" v-for="(book, index) in seziure" :key="index">


    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">Date </label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="book.date" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label"> Details</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="book.details" id="transliterateTextarea2">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<a @click="addNewRow">Add Another </a>
```

So, whenever I clicks Add Another @addNewRow I am getting a new input field but transliteration is not working. I think problem arises because id="transliterateTextarea2" works for only one input field.

So, when I click on @addNewRow how can I able to change the transliteration id.

My script is

```
addForm = new Vue({
el: "#addForm",
  data: {
          seziure:[
          {
             date: null,
             details: null,

          },
        ],
    },
methods: {
      addNewRow: function() {
          this.seziure.push({ date: null, details: null, });
        },
},
})
```

My transliteration script is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Google Transliterate API
      google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
          });

      function onLoad() {
        var options = {
            sourceLanguage:
                google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
            destinationLanguage:
                [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.MALAYALAM],
            shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
            transliterationEnabled: true
        };

        // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
        // options.
        var control =
            new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

        // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
        // 'transliterateTextarea'.
        var ids = [ "transliterateTextarea2" ];
        control.makeTransliteratable(ids);
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
    </script>
```

So, here I have added a transliteration id as  `var ids = [ "transliterateTextarea2" ];`
THIS ID is actually working for first input field only. So, when I click @addNewRow, an input field comes but transliteration is not working

So, when I click on@addNewRow how can I dynamically add id's. So, that I can get transliteration for that input fields too.

Please help me to have an answer.

I need transliteration works for, each new input fields I am adding.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try `Objuect.assign()`,the object you push to `seziure` maybe is not reactivity.  This is just my thoughts ,you can try only.

I were wrong..haha